# Gradle copy dependencies in built jar

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I'm searching a solution for adding my gradle dependencies in my built jar file.

For example, I've the dependency `com.fazecast:jSerialComm` and wanting to add the library in specific folder in the jar, library path should be`libs/jserialcomm/jSerialComm-2.0.2.jar`

Comment: You really want to include jSerialComm-2.0.2.jar into your built jar file? Or copy jSerialComm-2.0.2.jar into a directory relative to the built jar file and perhaps set the Class-Path in the manifest of the built jar file?

Comment: I want to copy all dependencies in the built jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your build.gradle:

```
jar {
  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

This will merge the content of all dependencies into the output jar.

See also http://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar.

In a different approach, one would copy the jars of the dependencies into the output jar (jars in jar), but that also requires writing a custom class loader.

UPDATE after edit of question:

The OP wants to take the second approach, which is employed as follows:

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.onslip.gradle-one-jar" version "1.0.5"
}

task awesomeFunJar(type: OneJar) {
    mainClass = 'com.github.rholder.awesome.MyAwesomeMain'
}
```

This will include all dependent jars into a lib directory in the output jar. It will also install a custom class loader, which loads jars from the lib directory in the jar. This is something that the standard class loader does not do, no matter how you tweak the class path.

See also https://github.com/Onslip/gradle-one-jar/

Comment: Thanks for your reply :). But how can y move dependencies in a specific path in the jar ?

Comment: Do you want to relocate class files into a different package? Then I recommmend the gradle shadow plugin: http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/#relocating_packages Otherwise it really would help if you could spill more details about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In a way, I wrote another, better written question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719718/gradle-include-dependencies-in-jar-specific-directories), which I think is easier to understand so tell me if your answer below is still valid.